# How to avoid writing multiple operators in If statement

Tags: javascript

I'm interested if it's possible to avoid using multiple operators to make an if statement when you want to check a similar condition for multiple variables. for example :

```
var good = 0;
var bad = 0;
var neutral = 0;

if(good === 0 && bad === 0 && neutral === 0){
  DO SMTH . . . 
}
```

instead of this if there's something that does it similar to the following :

```
if(good,bad and neutral === 0){
  do smth . . . 
}
```

So basically, just to avoid multiple operators. thank you!

Comment: you can do `if (good == bad == neutral == 0) {`

Comment: yea that works, thanks <3

Comment: @ControlAltDel why doesn't `good == bad == neutral` work? -- Ah classic loose type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Well... what about this

```js
def total = good + bad + neutral; 

if (total === 0) { 
   // do something
}
```

This works only if you are sure values are positive values.

Comment: i think ControlAltDel's answer is simpler, thanks tho !

Comment: I kinda want to down vote you on this, but I'll let it stand. IMO what you are doing here obscures the test as originally presented. But hey, who am I?